# How do i ensure implementation of a public static function with interface

Tags: java, interface, java-8

Since Java 8, we are able to define static and default methods in interface. But I need to ensure a public static method say `foo()` to be implemented in all the classes that implements a particular interface say `interface A`. How do I do that , or is it at all possible ?

The interface A:

```
package com.practice.misc.interfacetest;

public interface A {
    public static Object foo(); //Eclipse shows error : 'This method requires a body instead of a semicolon'
    String normalFunc();
}
```

Class B :

```
package com.practice.misc.interfacetest;

public class B implements A{

    @Override
    public String normalFunc() {
        return "B.normalFunc";
    }
//I need to ensure that I have to define function foo() too

}
```

Class C :

```
package com.practice.misc.interfacetest;

public class C implements A{

    @Override
    public String normalFunc() {
        return "C.normalFunc";
    }
//I need to ensure that I have to define function foo() too

}
```

Edit 1:
Actual case :

I have one public static method `getInstance()` (returning Singleton instance of that class) in all the implementing classes, and I want to ensure all the future classes other developers write must have that static method implemented in their classes. I can simply use reflection to return that instance by calling the `getInstance()` method from a static method of the interface,  but I wanted to make sure that everyone implements the `getInstance()` in all the implementing classes.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of `static`. It's mainly used for utility methods which are defined at one place and invoked everywhere else. There is no reason for having different implementations of it.

Comment: Please explain, *why* do you need this. Which problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @lexicore form the name of the package `com.practice...` this is not a *real* problem at all

Comment: You can not even enforce that the implementors are singletons, so what’s the point of enforcing the presence of a method that could return the single instance, if it was safe to assume that there is only one? How does the reflective code looking for that method learn about the existence of an implementation class?

Answer (score 8):

static methods from interface are *not* inherited (1). They are inherited in case of a class, but you can not override them (2); thus what you are trying to do is literally impossible.

If you want all classes to implement your method, why not simply make it `abstract` (and implicitly `public`) to begin with, so that everyone is *forced* to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Eugene already pointed out that static methods can not be overridden. I suggest that you extract the singleton behavior to a separate interface. For example:

```
public interface A {
    String normalFunc();
}

public class B implements A {
    @Override
    public String normalFunc() {
        return "B.normalFunc";
    }
    // TODO add getInstance for singleton
}

public interface Singleton {
    // TODO extensive javadoc to describe expected singleton behavior
    A getInstance();
}

public class BSingleton implements Singleton {
    @Override
    public A getInstance() {
        return B.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Finally you can use any object of type `BSingleton` to get the singleton object of `B`.

Comment: btw, in a future whatever version of java - we might get sealed interfaces, so that public methods are only implemented by already predefined classes and no one else...

Comment: @Eugene you can already enforce implementor restrictions by adding a method referencing a package-private type to the interface, which makes it impossible to implement the interface outside the package.

Comment: @Holger yes, I do know about that - this is sort of how we do it in our code, but I am not a huge fan of it